# Use inherited type as wrapper for an instance getter

Tags: c#, inheritance

Consider this two custom list clases.

```
public class CustomList1<T> : ISomeRandomInterface1, IEnumerable<Foo1> {
....
}

public class CustomList2<T> : ISomeRandomInterface2, IEnumerable<Foo2> {
....
}
```

Implementation is not relevant.

Is it possible to have a common parent type, so that the respective list instance can be retrieved in a getter kind of like this? :

```
public T getCustomList<T> () {
    // return CustomList1<T> or CustomList2<T>
    // being T the common parent type holder
}
```

The idea would to apply the same as when two classes implement the same interface, to use that interface as a type "holder" to retrieve or handle respective type instances in the code, but for a more complex case. Usually the base type acts as the "holder" type.

I think that as c# does not support multiple inheritance, I believe there is not a way to do this. I would like confirmation for this, and if there is any reasonable clean approach to achieve this for classes that are similar, but come from a different inheritance path.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just add another `ICommonAncestor` or similar and then constraint to that `where T: ICommonAncestor`

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, `ISomeRandomInterface` is generic? In `getCustomList` what will be `T`?

Comment: ISomeRandomInterface is not generic, its not `ISomeRandomInterface <T>`. In getCustomList, `T` would be the parent wrapper for `CustomList2<T>` and `CustomList1<T>`

Comment: what must return getCustomList? (T) or (CustomList1<T>/CustomList2<T>)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that understand you correctly... but I try answer :) 
You can define base type `BaseCustomList<T>` and inherit classes from him

```
public class CustomList1<T> : BaseCustomList<T>, ISomeRandomInterface1, IEnumerable<Foo1> {
....
}

public class CustomList2<T> : BaseCustomList<T>, ISomeRandomInterface2, IEnumerable<Foo2> {
....
}
```

now your function will be like that:

```
public BaseCustomList<T> getCustomList<T>()
{
    //return CustomList1<T> or CustomList2<T>
}
```